# django 1.3 - Correct way to define optional parameters for a class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views, parameter-passing, django-urls

I'm just getting my hands dirty with class-based views.

What is the correct way to pass default values for optional parameters to my class-based view?
for example I was previously pretty much doing this:
http://lethain.com/using-optional-parameters-in-django-urls/

Now I'm not so sure how to achieve the same effect in class based views. i.e. how do I define the class in the view, what should the entry in urls.py look like and how do I define default values for the optional parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url arguments are stored in `self.args` and `self.kwargs`. There are some examples in the [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering) section of the generic class based views docs.

You could pass default arguments by [including extra options in your url pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-include), or just set a default in your view when you fetch the value from `self.kwargs`.

```
my_value = self.kwargs.get('key', 'default_value')
```

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair. If I go the route of setting a default in my view, where is the appropriate place to put this? I'd like to standardize on where i do variable initialization. for e.g. get_queryset, get_context_data, somewhere else?

Comment: I personally think that you should initialise the variables in the methods where you need them, not all in one place. If you need to access a variable in more than one method, then write method to get the value (look at `get_year` in the date-based views for example). If you really want to initialise all the variables in one place, then I think you'll need to override `dispatch` to guarantee you can access the variables in all methods

Comment: yeah i'd rather not override dispatch every single time just to intialize variables. Is there somewhere in the docs that talks about the order of execution of the various functions? e.g. dispatch then get_queryset then get_context_data then etc....
Or do i have to hunt through the code for that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those who happen to be looking at this question, here is what I end up doing in 1.3. It  is pretty much the same as how i used to do it in 1.1 (except more verbose). (i.e. as described in the link in my question)

for e.g. relevant lines in urls.py might look like

```
...
# pass a default value of page = 1 for optional parameter page
url(r'^obj/list$', ObjListView.as_view(), {'page': 1}, name='obj_list'),
url(r'^obj/list/page(?P<page>[0-9]+)$', ObjListView.as_view(), name='obj_list'),
...
# both new and edit use the same class, but edit obviously needs an id for the object.
# i should probably just be using pk but whatever.
url(r'^obj/new$', ObjEditView.as_view(), name='obj_edit'),
url(r'^obj/edit/(?P<obj_id>[0-9]+)/$', ObjEditView.as_view(), name='obj_edit'),
```

in the case of ObjEditView class above, we may have something like this

```
class ObjEditView(UpdateView):
    ...
    form_class = ObjForm
    model=Obj
    ...

    # this puts our obj in self.object
    def get_object(self):
        # if the obj exists, intialize our variables with values from the obj instance
        # if it is a new obj, intialize accordingly
        try:
            obj = Obj.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['obj_id'])       
        except (KeyError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
            obj = Obj()

        return obj
```

As a corollary to my question to Alasdair in the comments above, the order of execution for the various functions inside the classes generally corresponds to the order they are in the documentation. i.e. in UpdateView get_object() comes before get_initial()

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related to this issue. I've been looking how to grab url parameters using class based views to add some extra context. You can do something like this:

```
url(r'^param1/(?P<param1>\d+)/param2/(?P<param2>\d+)/$', ClassDetailView.as_view())
```

and then in your view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ClassDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['param1'] = Model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['param1'])
    context['param2'] = Model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['param2'])
    return context
```

Then in your templates you'll have {{ param1 }} and {{ param2 }} objects available to you.

I'm new to this so feel free to hack on this if there is a better way to do it.